# From @awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser not able to download PDF in Ionic Cordova Applications

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

We are using `@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser` to open the webpage in the Ionic Cordova mobile application.

In the in-app browser we are loading the webpage that contains the download button. Expectation will be on click of that button it should download and it should save in mobile. But it's not working as expected.

The same webpage download functionality in browsers is working fine. Anyone, can you please suggest the fix?

These are the versions we are using

```
"@ionic/angular": "^7.5.4",
"@ionic/cordova-builders": "^10.0.0",
"@ionic/storage": "^4.0.0",
"@ionic/storage-angular": "^4.0.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^6.4.0",
"cordova-android": "12.0.1",
"@angular/cli": "^16.0.0",
```

We have upgraded `"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "6.0.0"` to `"@awesome-cordova-plugins/in-app-browser": "^6.4.0"`. Still not working.